# AndroidStudio - ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: linux, android-studio

I'm using following system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
$ uname -a
Linux X 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 12 11:03:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ rpm -qa | grep ^jdk
jdk1.8.0_91-1.8.0_91-fcs.x86_64
$
```

I download *android-studio-ide-143.2821654-linux.zip* from [Download Android Studio and SDK Tools | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) unzip it, and then while trying to run `studio.sh`, I'm getting following:

```
$ /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@28c97a5 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/alexus/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1415071428/jna6899341766790960590.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/alexus/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1415071428/jna6899341766790960590.tmp
[   7342]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Missing file '/home/alexus/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_23_x86.avd/config.ini'. 
[   7447]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - java.lang.NullPointerException 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:204)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.AndroidVirtualDevice.isSelectedByDefault(AndroidVirtualDevice.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallableComponent.updateState(InstallableComponent.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.ComponentCategory.updateState(ComponentCategory.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:103)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame.<init>(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.createFrame(FlatWelcomeFrameProvider.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:169)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:340)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:200)
    ... 16 more
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.1.1  Build #AI-143.2821654 
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_91 
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 
[   7450]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
```

I'm waiting and waiting and `Android Studio` window just hanging there and nothing else is happening(

Advise please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

following did the trick for me:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.android/
$ rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio2.1
$
```

Comment: or `mv ~/.android ~/.android.old; mv ~/.AndroidStudio2.1 ~/.AndroidStudio2.1.old` and restart the studio ...