# PyCharm not starting

Tags: python, pycharm

I have reinstalled `pycharm` hoping that I would fix an issue regarding highlighting all methods, including python predefined ones as **"Unresolved references"**.

This would highlight most of the code in red, even if I can run it properly. Anyway, after reinstalling, `pycharm` won't even start anymore.

`Pycharm` has started successfully on this PC previously. I tried clean reinstall (deleting `JetBrains` folder and then reinstalling, also checking the uninstall config and custom files in the uninstall prompt).

I have the output of running `pycharm` from the batch file but it is quite long so I won't append it here.

> at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.(PerformanceWatcher.java:85) at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor31.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImp l.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:47 ) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerI mpl.kt:664) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:49) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ServiceComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(ServiceComponentAdapter.kt:37) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:113) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:67) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:413) at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:395) at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:20) at com.intellij.diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher.getInstance(PerformanceWatcher.java:78) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.obtainPerformanceWatcher(IdeEventQueue.java:618) at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) 2020-10-20 12:36:01,232 [ 244904] ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - PyCharm 2020.2.3 Build #PY-202.7660.27 2020-10-20 12:36:01,233 [ 244905] ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; V endor: JetBrains s.r.o. 2020-10-20 12:36:01,233 [ 244905] ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 2020-10-20 12:36:01,234 [ 244906] ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:

This is the last part, if you can discern something from it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try reinstall visual studio. In my case it was the solution.

Comment: Just a guess...Look in your c:\users folder for any folder related to Pycharm and remove\rename it then restart Pycharm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215344/androidstudio-error-llij-ide-plugins-pluginmanager-java-lang-nullpointerex

Comment: @Mike67 I have nothing in c:\users related to Pycharm.

Comment: This seems a bug. Please report it to PyCharm. They have (usually) a great support (and it will help all users)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I submitted a report on their issue tracker platform, but no answer yet. I will look further into what I can do to contact jetbrains support, thank you.